# How to kill SQL process without rolling back

Tags: sql-server, rollback, kill-process

I have a trigger that is suppose to send an email, recently learned it was a bad idea, and it locked a process on my database. When I killed the process it is now stuck rolling back. I understand that I can only fix this with a server restart.

Now what I am trying to resolve is that same trigger has locked another table but I have not killed that process yet. I have heard there is a way to kill a process without rolling back but I can not find any information. It is on a dev database so we are not worried about bad data. This is Transact-SQL

Comment: Killing a transaction mid-run sounds like a terrible idea, as there is a reason they are grouped together.  Or am i missing the point?

Comment: If the process you kill is in mid transaction it will attempt to roll it back.  I don't think you can get around it.

Comment: So you want to break-off the sending of the email so that the transaction continues without an error (ie as though the email was sent)?

Comment: Yes TT that would be ideal. Our production data base is ran on the same server so we are trying to avoid taking it down to resolve a Dev issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process you kill is in mid transaction it will attempt to roll it back. You cannot get around it.